# Can I run both Ethereum and Bitcoin blockchain on the same PC?

Tags: bitcoin

I just completed the installation of both Bitcoin-Core on one PC and Ethereum on another PC. Both computer now have a complete blockchain and running wallet.

My question is: Could I run both Ethereum and Bitcoin-Core on one PC ?
Are there any reason for not running both Ethereum and Bitcoin-Core on one single PC ?
 Could there be interference as far as the internet access and ports, etc. ?
 Speed is not an issue since that PC will be dedicated strictly to cryptos. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

- *Could I run both Ethereum and Bitcoin-Core on one PC ?*

**Yes** if your hardware and software is compatible to all requirements. Please check both of them for their requirements.

- *Are there any reason for not running both Ethereum and Bitcoin-Core on one single PC?*

**Yes, main reason for me would be security**, especially if you run it on a server, where if you use it on your desktop PC, there should be no concerns unless you install any another software, some software could  contain some malicious code or a bug (ie. of the one of both wallets) which might harm your pc or even steal your coins. In general, there are many ways how your pc can be attacked/infected. There have been several exchanges which did make that mistake to put way to many wallets on one server.

- *Could there be interference as far as the internet access and ports, etc. ?*

**Yes there could be if you use for both wallets same port number in your configuration**. *If you do not make any change, they will use their default ports which do differ and would work properly. It could also always be that some another application uses defined port.*

Comment: Might want to add to the security part: there might be a bug in a wallet that could give an attacker access to other wallets on the computer.

Comment: I agree, I just wanted to point one of many possibilities, maybe more proper would be to remove trojan part and leave only malicious/harming part.

Comment: thx @lungj, I've added it

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you have enough disk space, memory, cpu and bandwidth, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could I run both Ethereum and Bitcoin-Core on one PC ? Yes You can
Are there any reason for not running both Ethereum and Bitcoin-Core on one single PC ? It will be slow
Could there be interference as far as the internet access and ports, etc. ? No